# QUndoStack remove specific command

Tags: c++, qt

How can I remove a specific command from a `QUndoStack`?

This command can be given by its index or pointer.

Comment: Providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help

Comment: Explaining why you (think you) want to do this would also help, as you might well be asking an XY question. As dtech indicated, it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to remove something from a sequential chain of events, thereby breaking the integrity of said chain. But maybe there is a use case that I can't think of... and maybe you have that use case here, if you were to tell us what it is.

Comment: Usually MWE is very useful. However, I don't see how it could clarify the question in this case. I have some `QUndoStack` and I want to remove the most recent command (I agree with @dtech that it does not make sense to remove other commands). How do I do that? It's a valid question and the answer is not trivial.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Qt 5.9, the [`QUndoStack::command(int index)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundostack.html#command) and [`QUndoCommand::setObsolete(bool obsolete)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html#setObsolete) functions are probably what you are looking for. The [relevant docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundostack.html#redo) from the `QUndoStack::redo()` command provide the explanation for how an obsoleted command is handled:

> If `QUndoCommand::isObsolete()` returns true for the current command, then the command will be deleted from the stack. Additionally, if the clean index is greater than or equal to the current command index, then the clean index is reset.

Comment: I fail to see how this works "by index or pointer". Or how it will work out in actual production code to begin with. I mean an obsolete command is supposed to not break the command chain, so using `setObsolete()` to a command that is not practically obsolete is likely to break the chain when the command is pruned. In the present form the answer is defacto a "link-only" answer and as such is against the SO guidelines. Consider improving it with practical example code to illustrate how exactly it is supposed to work.

Comment: It still doesn't explain how it is not going to break command chain.

Comment: `QUndoStack::command(int)` returns a `const QUndoCommand*` (for good reason) and `QUndoCommand::setObsolete(bool)` is non-`const`. How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

That's the thing about stacks - you only work on top of the stack. You can push and you can pop. You don't remove stuff from the middle of the stack.

In an undo-redo scenario this is even more important, as the order of commands must be diligently preserved for the whole thing to work. Otherwise you will break it.

Which is why it is called an "undo stack" and not "reverse arbitrary action whatchamacallit".

There is `QUndoStack::setIndex(int idx)` which will undo all commands until the provided index. But you cannot really remove only a specific command. You need to undo all commands until you reach and remove the one you want.

Answer (score 3):

As @dtech has pointed out, it does not make sense to undo a command which is not at the most recently pushed command (i.e., the command at top of the stack).

It does, however, make sense to undo the most recently pushed command.
And `QUndoStack` provides a very convenient way to do this: `QUndoStack::undo()`.

But, this does not *delete* the command, as it will still be available through `QUndoStack::push(...)`. To truly delete the command, it must be marked *obsolete* before undoing it:

```
auto* cmd = const_cast<QUndoCommand*>(undo_stack.command(undo_stack.count()-1));
cmd->undo();             // must be called explicitly
cmd->setObsolete(true);
undo_stack.undo();
```

It requires a `const_cast`, so I'd call it a hack. But for me, it works.